# Adding elements of each row to another array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays, `Result` and `X`. I would like to add non-zero row elements of `Result` to each element of `X`. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
Result=np.array([[ 0.        ,  -2.46421304,  -4.99073939,  -5.79902063,  0.        ],
       [-10.        ,  0.        ,  -4.99073939,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [-10.        ,  -2.46421304,  0.        ,  -5.79902063,  0.        ],
       [-10.        ,  0.        ,  -4.99073939,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  -2.46421304,  -4.99073939,  -5.79902063,  0.        ]])

X=np.array([10,2.46421304,4.99073939,5.79902063,0])
```

Desired output:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  10-2.46421304,  10-4.99073939,  10-5.79902063,  0.        ],
       [2.46421304-10.        ,  0.        ,  2.46421304-4.99073939,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [4.99073939-10.        ,  4.99073939-2.46421304,  0.        ,  4.99073939-5.79902063,  0.       ],
       [5.79902063-10.        ,  0.        ,  5.79902063-4.99073939,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0-2.46421304,  0-4.99073939,  0-5.79902063,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `numpy.where` to check if a value in `Result` is 0 or not and add accordingly:

```
out = np.where(Result!=0, X[:, None] + Result, Result)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  7.53578696,  5.00926061,  4.20097937,  0.        ],
       [-7.53578696,  0.        , -2.52652635,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [-5.00926061,  2.52652635,  0.        , -0.80828124,  0.        ],
       [-4.20097937,  0.        ,  0.80828124,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -2.46421304, -4.99073939, -5.79902063,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should accept enke's answer, but here's another way of doing it using `np.repeat`:

```
out = Result + np.repeat(X[:, np.newaxis], 5, axis=1) * (Result != 0)
```

I think the effect of `None` and `np.newaxis` is the same in this context vs the other answer.